# Why are variadic templates different than non-variadic, for only one argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, type-deduction

This code compiles just fine:

```
template <typename T1>
struct Struct {
};

struct ConvertsToStruct {
    operator Struct<int>() const;
};

template <typename T>
void NonVariadicFunc(Struct<T>);

int main() {
      NonVariadicFunc<int>(ConvertsToStruct{});
      return 0;
}
```

But an attempt to make it a little more generic, by using variadic templates, fails to compile:

```
template <typename T1>
struct Struct {
};

struct ConvertsToStruct {
    operator Struct<int>() const;
};

template <typename... T>
void VariadicFunc(Struct<T...>);

int main() {
      VariadicFunc<int>(ConvertsToStruct{});
      return 0;
}
```

What's going wrong?  Why isn't my attempt to explicitly specify `VariadicFunc`'s template type succeeding?

Godbolt link => https://godbolt.org/g/kq9d7L

Comment: Even weirder, if I take the address of the function, then it works: `(+VariadicFunc<int>)(ConvertsToStruct{});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 reasons to explain why this code can't compile.

The first is, the template parameter of a template function can be partially specified:

```
template<class U, class V> void foo(V v) {}

int main() {
      foo<double>(12);
}
```

This code works, because you specify the first template parameter `U` and let the compiler determine the second parameter. For the same reason, your `VariadicFunc<int>(ConvertsToStruct{});` also requires *template argument deduction*. Here is a similar example, it compiles:

```
template<class... U> void bar(U... u) {}

int main() {
      bar<int>(12.0, 13.4f);
}
```

Now we know compiler needs to do deduction for your code, then comes the second part: compiler processes different stages in a fixed order:

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

> Template argument deduction takes place after the function template name lookup (which may involve argument-dependent lookup) and before template argument substitution (which may involve SFINAE) and overload resolution.

Implicit conversion takes place at overload resolution, *after* template argument deduction. Thus in your case, the existence of a user-defined conversion operator has no effect when compiler is doing template argument deduction. Obviously `ConvertsToStruct` itself cannot match anything, thus deduction failed and the code can't compile.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with

```
VariadicFunc<int>(ConvertsToStruct{});
```

you fix only the **first** template parameter in the list `T...`.

And the compiler doesn't know how to deduce the remaining.

> Even weirder, I can take the address of the function, and then it works

It's because with `(&VariadicFunc<int>)` you ask for the pointer of the function (without asking the compiler to deduce the types from the argument) so the `<int>` part fix **all** template parameters.

When you pass the `ConvertToStruct{}` part

```
(&VariadicFunc<int>)(ConvertToStruct{});
```

the compiler know that `T...` is `int` and look if can obtain a `Struct<int>` from a `ConvertToStruct` and find the apposite conversion operator.